# Иногда вываливается ошибка table crashed. Что это значит?

Tags: python, mysql, django

Иногда происходит такой фейл. Причем он происходит рандомно и разово, после перезагрузки страницы все ок... Что это вообще может значить? И как это исправить?
Привожу текст из дебага.

```
Caught Warning while rendering: Table './megumi/address_city' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Request Method:

GET

Request URL:

http://megumi.jino.ru/addresses/

Django Version:

1.3.1

Exception Type:

TemplateSyntaxError

Exception Value:

Caught Warning while rendering: Table './megumi/address_city' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таблица БД повреждена вследствие каких-то коллизий, как-то: базы данных выключили не как положено и т.д. Сделайте repair таблички.

Comment: после обновления страницы, я так понял автоматом репар происходит, так как больше ошибка не вылезает.

Comment: Нет, это просто warning-сообщение БД (предупреждение, к остановке работы не приводит), а Джанга вам его ретранслирует в трэйсбэк. А так необходимо сделать repair таблицы.